# Probability of drawing 4 green balls from an urn when you're the last person to draw

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 24 balls, 8 of them being white, 8 green and 8 black. There are 6 people sequentially drawing these balls out of the urn (without replacement), with every person drawing 4 balls, and we have to determine the probability of the last one getting 4 green balls (being the only ones that are actually left).

The most direct route of figuring this out seems to be counting the number of ways these 24 balls can be 'assigned' to 6 people (and 20 balls to 5 people), but I can't find an elegant (non-terribly-tedious) way of doing this - if it does indeed exist? Probably there's a simpler way of solving this probability problem and I'm just missing something...

Comment: Is this different from just drawing $4$ of the $24$ balls and figuring out the probability of all $4$ being green?

Comment: It seemed to be different - but now I've changed my mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

calculate the probability that the person who draws first will get $4$ green balls. Then wonder whether this probability would be different for the person drawing last. I don't think so...

Comment: Ah, but of course - now it's trivial: (8*7*6*5)/(24*23*22*21) =~ .0066 Thanks! :)